# How can I define a custom template for woocommerce [products] shortcode?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

WooCommerce [products] shortcode has many features but lacks some 'template' feature. How can I define custom template like this:

```
[products class="simple-list"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your theme's function.php and add following

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_products_loop', 'roka_before_products_shortcode_loop', 1, 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_after_products_loop', 'roka_after_products_shortcode_loop', 0, 10 );

function roka_before_products_shortcode_loop( $atts ) {
    $GLOBALS[ 'roka_woocommerce_loop_template' ] =
        ( isset( $atts[ 'class' ] ) ? $atts[ 'class' ] : '' );
}

function roka_after_products_shortcode_loop( $atts ) {
    $GLOBALS[ 'roka_woocommerce_loop_template' ] = '';
}
```

Then override the file `content-product.php` by copying it to your theme's `woocommerce` folder.

find the line `<li <?php post_class(); ?>>` and add following after that:

```
<?php
    if(
        isset( $GLOBALS[ 'roka_woocommerce_loop_template' ] ) &&
        $GLOBALS[ 'roka_woocommerce_loop_template' ] == 'simple-list'
    ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        return;
    }
?>
```